# Receive ng-init value from the controller for angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I put data in the ng-init then I want to receive these value for my controller.

```
<div  ng-controller='hotelDetailCtrl' data-ng-init="mytest='hello'" class="col-sm-9 col-lg-9" >

app.controller('hotelDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function(){           
        alert($scope.mytest);
    };
});
```

But I can't get these value from my controller.Please help me and then explain about these case.

Comment: try `console.log($scope.mytest);` inside your controller

Comment: what is `detailUrl` ? where is `$scope.init()` called?

Comment: console.log($scope.mytest); it is not ok .  kamal pal

Comment: what you getting in console ?

Comment: So sorry Guillaume .I now updated my question.Thanks

Comment: The `ng-init` docs clearly say don't use it for things like this. Why can't you set that value in controller without ng-init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call init function inside your controller, but haven't called it inside your code, I assume this is what you planned to do:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('hotelDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function(){           
        alert($scope.mytest);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myapp">
      <div ng-controller='hotelDetailCtrl' data-ng-init="mytest='hello'; init();" class="col-sm-9 col-lg-9" >
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank iyerrama25.Your solution is ok for me.

Comment: I am now studying angular js.I want to know good reference address or book for angular js,javascript,php.Can you help me.Thank iyerrama25.

Comment: @MrMyo Even I am pretty new to the angular stuffs, the way I learned is by referencing the angularjs site itself: (https://angularjs.org/) It has some amazing links to its docs and videos (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) (https://www.youtube.com/user/angularjs, you can read up on it.
Other sources: https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning & https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: but outside init function $scope.mytest value shown as undefined